# Java overload: how to call more specific one

Tags: java, overload-resolution

My program parses `WebAssembly` instructions and makes decisions based on the context of the current instruction. So, the MWE for my algorithm looks like this:

```
public class Main {
    public interface Context {
        String name();
    }
    static class M implements Context {
        public String name() {
            return "Context M: ";
        }
    }
    static class N implements Context {
        public String name() {
            return "Context N: ";
        }
    }

    public interface Instruction {
        int getId();

        String run();
    }

    static class A implements Instruction {
        public int getId() {
            return 0;
        }

        public String run() {
            return "The work of A";
        }
    }

    static class B implements Instruction {
        public int getId() {
            return 1;
        }

        public String run() {
            return "The work of B";
        }
    }

    static void work(Context context, Instruction instruction) {
        switch (instruction.getId()) {
            case 0:
                workOnId0(context, (A) instruction);
                break;
            case 1:
                workOnId1(context, (B) instruction);
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to recognize instruction");
        }
    }

    static void workOnId0(Context context, A instruction) {
        System.out.println(context.name() + instruction.run());
    }

    static void workOnId1(Context context, B instruction) {
        System.out.println(context.name() + instruction.run());
    }

    static void workOnId1(N context, B instruction) {
        System.out.println("This is corner case logic for this context!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        N context = new N();
        B instruction = new B();

        work(context, instruction);
    }
}
```

As you can see from above, when my instruction is `B`, then the ordinary work should happen in `workOnId1`, but in case my context is specifically `N`, I would like some special work done, which is represented by a different overload of `workOnId1`.

Unfortunately, the special overload never gets called. How can I make the overload resolution work?

Comment: Yes and no. That question shows that, since the argument for `work` is of type `Context`, then `workOnId1(Context, whatever)` will always be selected. However, I don't know how to get around that at the moment

Comment: I wonder if using generics would work? `static void <T implements Context> work(T context, Instruction instruction)`

Comment: I don not think generics will help, because at runtime all those types will be `Object` so the compiler couldn't differ those methods

Comment: Is polymorphism an option here (putting workOnId1 inside Context for example)?

Comment: @Jaybird I don't think it is. The type of work to be done depends on the pair (context, instruction), so if I push everything down into the context, that would mean each context has to know about each instruction?

Answer (score 0):

`workOnId1(Context context, B instruction)` will always be called, because you have a `Context` object.

You are going to need to differentiate method calls by casting to `N`. If this doesn't work well within your model, since I'm guessing this is only a small example, you may need to rethink your overall design. A simple solution would be:

```
if(context instanceof N) {
   workOnId1((N)context, (B)instruction);
} else {
   workOnId1(context, (B) instruction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`you can change one line under case:1 as below to achieve your target`

```
switch (instruction.getId()) {
            case 0:
                workOnId0(context, (A) instruction);
                break;
            case 1:
                workOnId1((context instanceof N)? (N)context :context, (B) instruction);                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to recognize instruction");
        }
```

Comment: The result of the ternary expression will be of type Context - I don't think this will work